# twitter api post rate limit

Tags: python, api, twitter, limit, rate

Does anyone know Twitter's rate limit on posting?  Looking at their web page they claimed to not have one but I get an exception thrown if my program posts too fast...  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from http://help.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364 Jan 2015:

> #### Current Twitter limits
>
> The current technical limits for accounts are:
>
> - Direct messages (daily): The limit is 1,000 messages sent per day.
> - Tweets: 2,400 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are
>     counted as Tweets.

Answer (score 0):

The docs URLs have changed. You'll find more API info here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

Answer (score 0):

Twitter limits on Posts are on a per user bases with api 1.1.

Here are the rate limites for get requests: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits

And an explanation of get/post requests here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

It looks like the limit is 1000/day, but Twitter breaks rate limites down to 15 minute increments, so you might limit your api to around 9-10 tweets / 15min

https://support.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364